# App crash when I submit a new post to Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

This is the only Place my app crashes and one of the more important features

The LogCat tells me:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must create this type of ParseObject using ParseObject.create() or the proper subclass. 
>   at line 37.

I tried the `ParseObject.create()` however that just caused more problems (I may have done it incorrectly). How Should I code this?

Here is my newPost class:

```
public class newPost extends Activity {

private Button addButton;

private TextView postView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newpost);

    postView = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.postView));

    addButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton));
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //line 37 Below
            ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Posts");
            post.put("content", postView);
            post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        setResult(RESULT_OK);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error saving: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line

```
ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Posts");
```

with this

```
ParseObject post = ParseObject.create("Posts");
```

Comment: @Johnny you're right, this should not be needed. See my answer. I had the same problem.

Comment: API change? So weird.

Comment: i am facing same issue when i update data. if i create a new Parse Object than exception arrive is signUp first but i already login in same user

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to remove the '@ParseClassName' annotation in my model class. My understanding is that if I have a parse model class 'Posts' and I call 'registerSubclass(yourclassname)' in Application, then all I need is

```
Post obj = new Post();
```

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you've added the below line in the Application.java class where Parse is initialised

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Message.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably made a mistake in initialising Parse in your `Application` class. Or forgot to put `android:name=".YourApplicationClass"` in your Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I forgot to register my parse class as a subclass in my application extension:

```
public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        App application = this;

        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Posts.class); // <-- This is what you need

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                 .applicationId(EnvironmentConfig.appID)
                                 .server(EnvironmentConfig.serverName)
                                 .enableLocalDataStore()
                                 .build());

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```