# new ParseObject("Message") crashes app

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm attempting to create a new ParseObject like so:

```
ParseObject message = new ParseObject("Message");
```

When I run the app, it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must create this type of ParseObject using ParseObject.create() or the proper subclass.
```

This is my full code

```
ParseObject message = new ParseObject("Message");
message.put("content", "words go here");
message.saveInBackground();
```

More code can be posted if needed. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Your full code differs from your first line of code. The second one should work

Comment: ParseObject message = ParseObject.create("Message"); works completely.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I've tried both lines. the first line `= new Parseobject("Message");` causes the error, while the `= ParseObject.create("Message");` line does not add anything to the cloud.

Comment: Have you tried creating a Message class first in the dashboard?

Comment: @DaveS there is a `Message` class already on the dashboard.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the Parse SDK or an older version?

Comment: i am facing same issue when i update data. if i create a new Parse Object than exception arrive is signUp first but i already login in same user

Answer (score 4):

From this example: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects

You can create objects like so:

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

In fact similar code works in my app right now.

If you have created a Message model that extends ParseObject you may want to call new Message() as seen in this question:

https://www.parse.com/questions/new-parseobjectchat-crushes-the-app

This answer suggests using .create() may fix the problem but doesn't explain why.

[App crash when I submit a new post to Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727679/app-crash-when-i-submit-a-new-post-to-parse)

Also make sure you are properly initializing your app with the correct keys and you are using the latest version of the SDK.

Comment: i am facing same issue when i update data. if i create a new Parse Object than exception arrive is signUp first but i already login in same user

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've initialized Parse in your Application class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Register your parse models
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(GameScore.class); // for example

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(context)
                .applicationId(APPLICATION_ID)
                .server(SERVER)
                .build()
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a subclass, example:

```
@ParseClassName("Rating")
public class ParseRating extends ParseObject{
```

You are going to get this error typing `new ParseObject("Rating")`

The solution is to create a `new ParseRating()`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks,